# Is it possible to have a critical region based off a condition?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a website where the frontend auto saves data entered to the backend.  It is possible that these saves maybe very close together, and I want to lock the saving of results on a per user basis.

I don't want to use a simple 'lock' as that will block all users trying to save.

Is there anyway to do this in .NET?

Comment: What prevents you from having one lock object per user?

Comment: Do you mean something like having a dictionary of lock objects indexed by UserID?  Then for then dynamically look up the user lock just before we enter the critical region?  Sounds like it would work.  Would the list have to be static so that it's shared across threads?

Comment: A critical region within a conditional, sure (just put the lock inside an if branch). But that doesn't seem like what you're actually looking for. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a lock object per user sounds reasonable. I would also advise you to use Monitor.TryEnter instead of lock and just skip the save if there is already a save in progress. Something like this:

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _locksByUser = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

public void Save(string userId) {
   var lock = _locksByUser.GetOrAdd(userId, new object());
   if (Monitor.TryEnter(lock)) {
       try {
       //do save here
       }
       finally {
           Monitor.Exit(lock);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Mike, can you expand on why using `Monitor.TryEnter` instead of a `lock` in this case? I think lock(obj) is shortcut for the monitor and try catch stuff - but I might be missing a nuance

Comment: Mike, that's a great solution.  Kind of what I had in mind but your solution is even better with the use of a concurrent dictionary.  I wonder the same thing as @Prescott though regarding simply using a lock.

Comment: @Prescott I think he explained it: if we fail to enter, `lock` will wait. `TryEnter` will skip the rest, which is what we want because the user is already being saved, no need to do it again directly afterwards.

Comment: @Prescott, effectively lock is a shortcut for Monitor.Enter... The nuance is that in my example I'm using Monitor.TryEnter, which doesn't wait if the object is already locked as Konrad mentioned.